# Laravel - JS [ajax] Var must be constant

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, laravel-blade

i will be happy if someone know how to do this and why i m getting error , i would like to pass "var size" inside route() method inside forelse is it somehow passible ?

whot it do ?

based on radio box ( if size M and L are avaible there will be 2 radioboxes ), then if user click on add to card it gets Value of radio box for example ( 6 ) = L them pass it to ajax route

Error :

> Use of undefined constant size - assumed 'size' (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\EcSc\resources\views\shop\home.blade.php)

JS :

```
        <script>
            var CartCount = {{ Session::has("cart") ? Session::get("cart")->totalQty : "0" }} ;
            var size;
            @forelse($products as $productsjs)
            $("#product-{{$productsjs->id}}").click(function () {
                var radios{{$productsjs->id}} = document.getElementsByName('radio-{{$productsjs->id}}');
                for (var i = 0, length = radios{{$productsjs->id}}.length; i < length; i++) {
                    if (radios{{$productsjs->id}}[i].checked) {
                        // do whatever you want with the checked radio
                        size = radios{{$productsjs->id}}[i].value;

                        // only one radio can be logically checked, don't check the rest
                        break;
                    }
                }
                $.ajax({
                    type: "get",
                    url: "{{route("product.addToCartAjax", $productsjs->id, size)}}", // insert product with specific size into session
                    success: function () {
                        CartCount++;
                        $("#shoppingCartCounter").html(CartCount);
                        console.log("Produkt bol pridani");
                        console.log("Velkost produktu je : " + size); // size contain value of checked radio box 
                    }
                })
            });
            @empty
            @endforelse
        </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't print the javascript variable in PHP. Think of `{{ }}` as `<?php ?>`. If you just insert it in there, it may look like `<?php echo size; ?>` which won't work, as obviously size will look like a constant here, which of course is undefined (your error).

Instead, you need to declare the variable in php. However, since you're doing this after run time, there's no way that you're going to be able to assign a PHP variable after the page has been rendered. So what are your alternatives?

## 1 - Construct the route manually: (recommended, easiest)

```
url: '/products/' + {{$productsjs->id}} + '/add-to-cart-ajax/' + size
```

## 2 - Use a client side route generator for Laravel, such as [La Route](https://github.com/aaronlord/laroute) (harder, but more dynamic and reusable)

```
laroute.route('product.{id}.addToCartAjax.{size}', {id: '{{$productsjs->id}}', size: size});
```

## 3 - Other generic solutions such as generating the route ahead of time and dynamically modifying it with javascript (ugly, non-portable)

Comment: aaa i see it my JS var is inside {{ }} :o gonna try delete it :) and i post result here